# Convergence of steepest descent dynamics under weak convexity assumption

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, convex-optimization, gradient-flows

Let $f\colon \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ be smooth and assume that

- $f$ is a convex function (its Hessian is positive semi-definite);
- $f$ is bounded from below, in particular $\inf_{z \in \mathbb R^d} f(z) > - \infty$.

Let $x(t)$ denote the solution to the differential equations
$$
\dot x(t) = - \nabla f\bigl(x(t)\bigr), \qquad x(0) = x_0.
$$
**Question:** Are there classical results on gradient descent stating that
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}f\bigl(x(t)\bigr) = \inf_{z \in \mathbb R^d} f(z) =: I. \qquad \qquad (1)
$$
for all initial conditions $x_0 \in \mathbb R^d$?
Note that $f\bigl(x(t)\bigr)$ may converge even if $x(t)$ does not converge,
for example in the case $f(x) = e^{-x}$.

**Proof of convergence when $f$ is coercive**,
that is to say when $f(z) \to \infty$ in the limit as $|z| \to \infty$.
It is sufficient to show that, for all $\varepsilon > 0$,
the dynamics $x(t)$ reaches the set $A_{\varepsilon} := \{z: f(z) \leq I + \varepsilon \}$ eventually.
These sets are convex, and also bounded by coercivity.
Any minimizing sequence has a convergent subsequence by compactness of $A_{\varepsilon}$,
and so there exists a (possibly non-unique) minimizer $z_*$ of $f$.
We denote
$$
R_{\varepsilon} = \sup_{z \notin A_{\varepsilon}} \|z - z_*\| > 0.
$$
Let us fix $\varepsilon > 0$ and show that the norm $\|\nabla f\|$ is bounded from below by a strictly positive constant $C_{\varepsilon}$ uniformly for $z \notin A_{\varepsilon}$.
Fix $z \notin A_\varepsilon$ and let $y$ denote the intersection between the boundary of $A_{\varepsilon}$ and the segment linking $z_*$ and $z$.
Since $f(y) = I + \varepsilon$,
we have by convexity
$$
    \langle \nabla f(y), z_* - y \rangle \leq f(z_*) - f(y) = - \varepsilon,
$$
Since $f$ is convex, it also holds that
$$
    \langle \nabla f(z) - \nabla f(y), z - y \rangle \geq 0,
$$
and so
$$
    \|\nabla f(z) \| \|z - y\| \geq \langle \nabla f(y), z - y \rangle
    = \frac{\|z-y\|}{\|y-z_*\|} \langle \nabla f(y), y - z_* \rangle
    \geq \frac{\|z-y\|}{\|y-z_*\|} \varepsilon \geq \|z-y\| \frac{\varepsilon}{R_{\varepsilon}}.
$$
Canceling $\|z-y\|$ on both sides,
we obtain the desired lower bound.
The conclusion then easily follows from the fact that
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \bigl(f(x(t))\bigr) = \bigl\langle \nabla f\bigl(x(t)\bigr),  \dot x(t) \bigr\rangle = - \| \nabla f\bigl(x(t)\bigr) \|^2.
$$

**Proof that (1) holds if $d = 1$**.
If $f$ attains its infimum the proof is not difficult,
so we suppose that $f$ does not have a minimizer.
In this case either $f'(z) > 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb R^d$ or $f'(z) < 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb R^d$.
Without loss of generality, assume the latter case holds.
Then clearly $I = \lim_{z \to \infty} f(z)$ and $x(t)$ is a strictly increasing function of $t$.
It is impossible that $x(t) \to x_*$ for some $x_* < \infty$,
because $\dot x$ can be bounded from below uniformly in a neighborhood of $x_*$.
Consequently, it must hold that $x(t) \to \infty$ and so $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(x(t)) = I$.

**Therefore**, the case that is interesting is when $f$ is non-coercive with $d > 1$. Then either $f$ attains its infimum or not, and I am particularly interested in the latter situation: $f$ does not have a minimizer.

Comment: It's a reasonable question but, in order to avoid the closure "due to lack of context", please add details about what you know, e.g. a reference to a proof that the claim holds if $f$ attains its minimum.

Comment: For those who might be wondering, $f(x) = e^x$ is a simple $d = 1$ example of a function satisfying OP's three bulleted properties.

Comment: It's fine from my viewpoint (I actually upvoted the question), but somebody downvoted too. By the way, the question is also reasonable even if the function is unbounded from below.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks and yes, that is true; the question makes sense also if $f$ is unbounded from below.

Comment: What method do you mean by gradient descent? Constant stepsize?

Comment: @R.W.Prado No discretization, just continuous-time.

Comment: @RobertoRastapopoulos would you be okay with a proof in discrete time? (just asking - I don't have a proof yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, a colleague found the following simple solution.
Assume for contradiction that
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} f\bigl(x(t)\bigr) = I + 2\varepsilon
$$
for some $\varepsilon > 0$,
and let $x_*$ be such that $f(x_*) \leq I + \varepsilon$.
Then, using the convexity of $f$,
we have
$$
    \frac{1}{2}
    \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \bigl(x(t)-x_*\bigr)^2 
    = - \Bigl\langle \nabla f\bigl(x(t)\bigr), x(t) - x_* \Bigr\rangle
    \leq \bigl(f\bigl(x_*\bigr) - f\bigl(x(t)\bigr)\bigr) \leq - \varepsilon,
$$
and so $\bigl(x(t)-x_*\bigr)^2 \to -\infty$,
which is impossible.